# Get value of input type number in c#

Tags: c#, htmlcontrols

**example:**

```
<input id="txtEntQty" type="number" min="1" max='<%# Eval("RemQty")%>' value='<%# Eval("RemQty")%>'>
```

**code behind:**

```
int ASSIGNQTY = Convert.ToInt32((row.Cells[12].FindControl("txtQty") as **?????**).value);
```

Comment: Why as? Just use the return string. row.Cells[12].FindControl("txtQty").Value or something like it.

Comment: i am used this control in gridview and i want to get value of number control when i click on save button

Comment: i am getting this error:
System.Web.UI.Control' does not contain a definition for 'Value' and no extension method 'Value' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Do you use WebForms or MVC?

Comment: i am useing only webforms not mvc

Comment: Try ((TextBox)row.Cells[12].FindControl("txtQty")).Value

Comment: getting :
'((System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox)(row.Cells[12].FindControl("txtQty")))' is null

Comment: i think texbox it is webcontrol and i am inserting html number type control so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68063/discussion-between-ketan-mevada-and-luba).

Comment: Insert a TextBox Ctrl instead of an input element. Use input elements on your mvc projects instead.

Comment: but i don't get max and min property in textbox control

Comment: ((TextBox)row.Cells[12].FindControl("txtQty")).Attributes["max"]. You can write it inside your view without problems, too.

Comment: {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: i want look like something
(input[type="number"])row.Cells[12].FindControl("txtQty").value)

because i am using html number type control

Comment: Try it or google around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this make your input `runat="server"`

```
<input type="number" id="txNUm" runat="server" />
```

And in .cs code where you want to get value write thiss

```
System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl input = (System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlInputControl)gvrow.Cells[5].FindControl("txNUm");
int ASSIGNQTY = Convert.ToInt32(input.Value);
```

Comment: what is gvrow.cells?

Comment: @JonathanBurgosGio gvrow is current row of gridview and cells are columns of current row in context.